# Why is a java application causing 100% CPU usage in Mac OS X Dock?

Tags: macos, java, glassfish

I develop java applications using the Glassfish application server and when I deploy/undeploy applications the CPU usage of the Dock in Mac OS X shoots up to >100% and the system becomes unresponsive for 1-2 minutes.

Glassfish is not run from the dock, it's started manually using a shell script so I don't see what the Dock has to do with it.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: How big is the application you're deploying to Glassfish?  What version of Glassfish?  There are bugs that come up about slow deployment from time to time (for example: http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-17094).

Comment: Glassfish 3.1.1, also happens on latest 3.1.2-b20. The war is about 30Mb, Java EE, Hibernate... and I would usually expect it to take a minute or two to fully deploy so it's not really the time involved but the fact that it interferes with the Dock making it impossible to switch to other apps etc. during the deploy/undeploy. It is worse on undeploy via either the admin console or asadmin, the logs and gui indicate that the app has successfully undeployed but the dock process subsequently goes to 100% cpu for a minute or more.

Comment: It's probably "some bug" recommend doing a jstack on it when it's using 100% cpu, try to find the hotspot...